# Need to show only one month in range picker selection area antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, daterangepicker

I'm using **antd** calendar **RangePicker** for my react app.i want to show only one month of calendar dropdown upon selection, instead of two months default.

```
<div className="DatePickerBar">
   <RangePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD"
     className="DateInput"
     value={[moment(dateRange.from), moment(dateRange.to)]}
     onChange={this.onRangeChange}
     allowClear={false}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a codesandbox link/preview will help!

Comment: codesandbox: https://wvt2t.csb.app/

Answer (score 3):

For antd@4 it can be possible using this CSS

```
.ant-picker-panels > *:first-child button.ant-picker-header-next-btn {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.ant-picker-panels > *:first-child button.ant-picker-header-super-next-btn {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.ant-picker-panels > *:last-child {
  display: none !important;
}

.ant-picker-panel-container, .ant-picker-footer {
  width: 280px !important;
}

.ant-picker-footer-extra > div {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use css for the 2nd column

```
.ant-picker-time-panel {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is using the `showTime` feature, but re-formatting to exclude hour and minute selection(default), i.e.:

```js
<div className="DatePickerBar">
   <RangePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD"
     className="DateInput"
     value={[moment(dateRange.from), moment(dateRange.to)]}
     onChange={this.onRangeChange}
     allowClear={false}
     showTime
     format="YYYY/MM/DD"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it shows an empty column with header having the date, Is there anyway to remove this empty time column. ?

Comment: Does this sandbox help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-resonance-7904l?file=/src/App.js?

Comment: It is not the exact outcome I need. Better I can remove the 2nd column entirely.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who stumbles on this, there is a quick workaround:

- set class name of popup:

```js
   <RangePicker
     ...
     popupClassName="dateRangePicker"
     ...
   />
```

- manipulate the css:

```css
    .dateRangePicker .ant-picker-panel:nth-child(2){
        display: none;
      }
    
      .dateRangePicker .ant-picker-panel:nth-child(1) button{
        visibility: visible !important;
      }
```

This will hide the second panel and display the necessary icons for month switching